# Autocomplete com dois tipos de dados

Tags: javascript, regex

Como faço para carregar dois tipos de dados no mesmo input que está recebendo um autocomplete (plugin EayAutocomplete). Gostaria que aparece as opções por número de cnpj e razão social da empresa. Não manjo de expressões regulares, alguém poderia ajudar?

Segue o html:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Nome do Fornecedor / CNPJ</label><br>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="autoCompl" id="autoCompl" value="" placeholder="Procurar">
</div>
```

Segue o json:

```
[
  {"dados":"Ericsson Sistemas de Energia Ltda 1029384756/00"},
  {"dados":"Ericsson Telecomunicações 0192837465/00"},
  {"dados":"Telefônica do Brasil Ltda 5647382910/00"},
  {"dados":"Tim do Brasil Ltda 3669278723/00"},
  {"dados":"Telemar Telecomunicações Ltda 5463782113/00"},
  {"dados":"Vivo do Brasil Ltda 7588697132/00"},
  {"dados":"Oi Telecomunicações Ltda 1253467264/00"},
  {"dados":"Claro do Brasil Ltda 0980966535/00"},
  {"dados":"Telecomunicações Ltda 3562989272/00"}
]
```

Segue o script:

```
var options = {
    url: "solicitar_acesso.json",
    getValue: function(element){
        var dados = element.dados;
        var array = dados.split(" ");
        var resul1 = array[0];
        var resul2 = array[1];
        var filtro = new RegExp('[0-9]');
        var filter = ('[a-z]', 'ig');
        if (resul1.search(filtro) || resul2.search(filter)) {
            return dados;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    },
}
```

Comment: Não sei como funciona esse plugin, `element` faz referencia ao elemento de id `autoCompl` ?

Comment: Não, element é o parametro que vem do json, como no json que está no exemplo, element mostra os valores da chaves 'dados' do json, deu pra entender :)

Comment: E como eu capturo os dados que estão sendo digitados no `input` para poder fazer o teste de sugestão?

Comment: Desculpa, não entendi a pergunta?

Comment: Não entendo de javascript, mas se ajudar, tem esse Regex: `((?:[^\x00-\x7F]|[a-zA-Z]\s*)+)(\d+\/\d{2})` e a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/3llKaL/1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Utilizando a expressão regular de [@danieltakeshi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/256282/autocomplete-com-dois-tipos-de-dados#comment526536_256282), você pode dividir os dados em:

- `match[1]=>"%EMPRESA% "` `<- Note a presença de um espaço aqui`
- `match[2]=>"%CNPJ%"`

Porém também seria possível, sem regex, dar um [`String#split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), [`String#pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) e [`String#join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) no ultimo espaço:

```
var array = "Foo Bar Baz 0000000000/00".split(" ");
var cnpj = array.pop(); // 0000000000/00
var empresa = array.join(" "); // Foo Bar Baz
```

E como comentou [@Guilherme Lautert](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/256282/autocomplete-com-dois-tipos-de-dados#comment525877_256282), na sua função não parece ter nenhuma referência para a entrada do texto (A não ser que o plugin utilizado tenha-o e você não a utilizou), então estou usando esta variável para isso:

```
var input = document.getElementById("autoCompl");
```

Outra coisa que notei, você criou duas variáveis "filtro" que estão dando match em um mesmo texto (`element`, que [você disse](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/256282/autocomplete-com-dois-tipos-de-dados#comment525874_256282) ser os textos dos dados), sendo assim, ele sempre retornará `true`, pois nenhuma entrada de texto está sendo verificada.

---

Como não é possível implementar esse seu plugin no snippet do SOpt, eu criei uma "simulação" do auto completar abaixo, altere se precisar.

## Snippet

```js
var dados =   [{"dados":"Ericsson Sistemas de Energia Ltda 1029384756/00"},
  {"dados":"Ericsson Telecomunicações 0192837465/00"},
  {"dados":"Telefônica do Brasil Ltda 5647382910/00"},
  {"dados":"Tim do Brasil Ltda 3669278723/00"},
  {"dados":"Telemar Telecomunicações Ltda 5463782113/00"},
  {"dados":"Vivo do Brasil Ltda 7588697132/00"},
  {"dados":"Oi Telecomunicações Ltda 1253467264/00"},
  {"dados":"Claro do Brasil Ltda 0980966535/00"},
  {"dados":"Telecomunicações Ltda 3562989272/00"}]

var options = {
    url: "solicitar_acesso.json",
    getValue: function(element){
        var dados = element.dados;
        var array = dados.match(/((?:[^\x00-\x7F]|[a-zA-Z]\s*)+)(\d{10}\/\d{2})/);
        var resul1 = array[1];
        var resul2 = array[2];
        var input = document.getElementById("autoCompl");
        if ((resul1.toUpperCase().startsWith(input.value.toUpperCase()) || resul2.toUpperCase().startsWith(input.value.toUpperCase()))&&input.value) {
            return dados;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    },
}

function procurar(){
    var resultado = document.getElementById("tempResult");
    resultado.innerHTML="";
    var a = 0;
    dados.forEach(function(){ 
        var r = options.getValue(dados[a]);
        if (r)
          resultado.innerHTML += r+"<br>";
        a++;
    });
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Nome do Fornecedor / CNPJ</label><br>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="autoCompl" id="autoCompl" value="" placeholder="Procurar" onchange="procurar();" onkeypress="this.onchange();" onpaste="this.onchange();" oninput="this.onchange();">
    <br><label id="tempResult"></label>
</div>
```